# Vue2 $refs empty when DOM element not visible

Tags: ajax, vuejs2

I'm trying to play a video with Vue2, and I'm using the following code:

HTML:

```
<video ref='wave' id='wave' :src='audio.wave'></video>
```

Then I do an AJAX request to get the URL of the video. I know I have to save "this" in another variable, so use "vm" variable:

```
  var vm=this;
    $.post( {blah, blah} ).done(function( response ) {
      var json=JSON.parse(response);
      console.log(vm.$refs); // outputs empty object
    });
```

When I console.log() "vm.$refs" it displays an empty object:

> {}

But, If I manually type the command into the browser console after the $.post request has completed, it contains a reference to my element:

> {wave: video#wave}

Any help gratefully received

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you are making the post request in `created` hook.

> An important note about the ref registration timing: because the refs
> themselves are created as a result of the render function, you cannot
> access them on the initial render - they don’t exist yet!

> (from https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref)

if you make the post request in `mounted` hook, the `$refs` should be ready and you will be able to use it.

or... using [nextTick](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-nextTick) would also solve the issue (if the element will be mounted in the next DOM update cycle.).

```
var vm = this;
$.post({ blah, blah }).done(function(response) {
  var json = JSON.parse(response);
  // added
  vm.$nextTick(()=>{
    console.log(vm.$refs); 
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks - that's really helpful!